# Coral Dev Board Windows 10 setup

Tags: google-coral

I followed the windows host instructions described in the https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/

When I run command mdt devices, I get following exception always:

```
$ mdt devices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ram\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\ram\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts\mdt.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in
<module>
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mdt\main.py", line 162, in
main
    exit(command.run(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mdt\devices.py", line 43, i
n run
    self.discoverer.discover()
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mdt\discoverer.py", line 40
, in discover
    self.zeroconf = Zeroconf()
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zeroconf\__init__.py", line
 2508, in __init__
    self._listen_socket, self._respond_sockets = create_sockets(
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zeroconf\__init__.py", line
 2343, in create_sockets
    respond_socket = new_respond_socket(i, apple_p2p=apple_p2p)
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zeroconf\__init__.py", line
 2302, in new_respond_socket
    respond_socket = new_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Ram\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zeroconf\__init__.py", line
 2250, in new_socket
    s.bind((bind_addr[0], port, *bind_addr[1:]))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Versions of my set up:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5

$ mdt version
MDT version 1.5.2
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. Skipping some IP addresses solved the issue. Try this code:

```
import logging
import zeroconf
import ifaddr

for adapter in ifaddr.get_adapters():
    print("IPs of network adapter ", adapter.nice_name)
    for ip in adapter.ips:
        print("   %s/%s", ip.ip, ip.network_prefix)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("zeroconf").setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
z = zeroconf.Zeroconf()
```

From the log, find

> INFO:zeroconf:Address not available when adding XXX.XXX.XX.XX to multicast group, it is expected to happen on some systems

Along with the Zeroconf log, there should be a list of ip addresses and names. Please find the name of the hardware that is causing the problem.

Now, open `zeroconf/__init__.py` and goto `get_all_addresses()` and replace the code with below

```
adapters = [x for x in ifaddr.get_adapters() 
    if not "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" in x.nice_name
    and not "Bluetooth Device" in x.nice_name]

return list(set(addr.ip for iface in adapters for addr in iface.ips if addr.is_IPv4))
```

Please replace the "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" and "Bluetooth Device" with the appropriate name.

This is not a neat way, so I'd be open to better answers.